# Flask: Save requests.get API data to sqlite database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, python-requests

I have tried unsuccesfully to save fetched API data to sqlite database in a Flask app. I have used requests.get() to extract external API data to dataframe. **The function "extract_to_df_race" works when i test it in Jupyter Notebook.** I have placed try-except statements to print error messages to console. Since, there were no error messages logged in console, I initally presume that the data has been successfully fetched and save to database. However, upon checking the database, none of the records have been saved.

I have used a custom Flask command to execute the 'historical_records' function to one-off load the database.

Are there any better methods of debugging that i could try?

**app/api/log.py**

```
from app import app
from app.models import Race, db
from app.utils  import * 
import click

@app.cli.command()
def historical_records():
    seasons = [2015]
    races_round = range(1,5)
    df_races = extract_to_df_race('results', seasons, races_round)
    save_races_to_db(df_races, db)

def save_races_to_db(df_races, db):
    for idx,row in df_races.iterrows():
        r = Race()
        r.url = df_races.loc[idx,"url"]
        r.season = df_races.loc[idx,"season"]
        r.raceName = df_races.loc[idx,"raceName"]
        db.session.add(r)
        try:
            db.session.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            db.session.rollback()
            eprint(str(e))
```

To execute historical_records function from virtual environment, i ran `"export FLASK_APP=app/api/log.py"`, then `"flask historical_records"`

**app/utils.py**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import sys

def eprint(*args, **kwargs):
    print(*args, file=sys.stderr, **kwargs)

def extract_to_df_race(results_type, seasons, races_round):

    df_races = pd.DataFrame()

    if results_type == 'results':   
        for s in seasons:
            for r in races_round:
                try:
                    response = requests.get(API_URL)
                    response.raise_for_status()
                    dictionary = response.content 
                    dictionary = json.loads(dictionary)
                    races = transform_func(dictionary, s, r) 
                    df_races = pd.concat([df_races, races])
                except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
                    eprint(err)
                    sys.exit(1)


        return df_races
```

**Races model**

```
class Race(db.Model, Serializer):
    __tablename__ = 'races'
    raceId = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    season = db.Column(db.Integer)
    raceName = db.Column(db.String(50))

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Race, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Can you please show Race model?

Comment: Also when you trying to catch sqlalchemy based exceptions always specify which one you would like to catch. For list of available visit: [link](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/exceptions.html). I.e. to catch unique violation use `IntegrityError`.

Comment: Also you do not import `eprint` and `extract_to_df_race` in **log.py**

Comment: @needtobe updated. eprint and extract_to_df_race is found in utils, which i have imported to log.py